# Covid-19-virus tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I was surprised to discover that the tag regarding the current pandemic is [covid-19-virus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19-virus). As the blurb describing the tag correctly explains, “Covid-19” is not the name of the virus but the name of the disease. It's also shorter, unambiguous and, by now, well established (which might not have been the case a few months ago). Any reason not to change it to [covid-19](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes makes sense to rename and make synonyms to ensure that all tags point to the same main tag. I suggest:

- [covid-19-virus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19-virus) -> [covid-19](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19)
- [sars-cov-2-virus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sars-cov-2-virus) -> [covid-19](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19)
- [sars-cov-2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sars-cov-2) -> [covid-19](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19)

Please add any other synonym suggestion you might have to this list. Will take care of this as we go.

Comment: Why would anyone want "sars-cov-2-virus"?  "SARS-Corona-Virus-2-Virus" is redundant and sounds silly.  It shouldn't exist as a synonym.

Comment: @RayButterworth Synonyms on SE should not be considered as synonyms in the pure grammatical sense. Synonyms exist to help users avoid confusion. Someone might type sars-cov-2-virus or a subset of these keywords into the tag textboxt and they will find the right main tag: covid-19.